# Joomla 3 Flexicontent form custom plugin

Tags: php, forms, joomla, jform

After hours of googling and experimenting, I gave up :(

I need to add form to my articles in Joomla 3, that collects data from article's additional fields and emails them. Articles are managed by Flexicontent. Flexicontent overrides standard content manager so I tried to make a plugin inside 'content' plugins (later I tried 'flexicontent' as well). Basing on articles:
http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component
http://betweenbrain.com/notes/72-fun-with-joomla-forms
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/plugins/user/profile/profile.php#L168

which all override some kind of form (user, content or contact).

I made my plugin folder, plugin php file, plugin manifest (xml file) and xmls with form fields. Then in my php file I wrote onContentPrepareForm(), as instructed. However, when I checked "$this" variable in my flexiconent template, there were no signs of any form. How should I place this form in my template?

Comment: Please ask your question on the dedicated [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) site ;)